# What are the requirements to unlock a specialisation?

Tags: the-division-2

What activity completions are needed to unlock the ability to pick a specialisation in the Base of Operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specialisations become available when you reach World Tier 1. This is done by first levelling your agent to level 30 and then completing all the available Strongholds.

There are three to complete to reach World Tier 1.

- District Union Area
- Roosevelt Island

  - and then
- Capitol Building

Once these are completed you can visit Coop in the Base of Operations. The desk to his left will be the new Specializations station.

Comment: I would add that you also need to be level 30 since it's a requirement.